# java.lang.InstantiationException although a NoArgsConstructor is present

Tags: java, exception, inner-classes, instantiationexception

when I want to create an instance of my object `TransLog`, an `InstantiationException` is thrown even though I created a No-Args constructor in the class `TransLog`:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: TransactionLogger$TransLog.<init>()
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412)
        ... 20 more
```

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
private class TransLog {
  public TransLog() {
  } 

  private int x; 
  private int y;
}
```

I create the instance in this way:

```
TransLog log = (TransLog) clazz.newInstance(); // clazz is TransLog.class
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared your `TransLog` class as a **non-static** inner class within the `TransactionLogger` class.

That means the `TransLog` class has an implicit member variable
referencing the enclosing `TransactionLogger` instance,
and the constructors have an implicit additional argument of that type.

It seems you don't want that.
Therefore you need to declare the inner class as `static`:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
private static class TransLog {
    public TransLog() {
    }

    private int x;
    private int y;
}
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot!
I didn't even think about the modifier anymore!